# SIGCONT on MACOS X behavior

Tags: c, signals, darwin, xnu

When I call waitpid() with the WUNTRACED|WCONTINUED options set in order 
to know when the child process receives SIGSTOP's and SIGCONT's. The 
SIGSTOP is not the problem, but I am unable to catch sigcont signal using  WIFCONTINUED(stat) function but program is continuing when I am sending signal from terminal. The 
appended code illustrates the problem: SIGCONTs to the child do 
continue the child process but waitpid() remains blocked and the 
SIGCONT is just not noticed by the parent.

The code is however fully functional under Sparc Solaris 2

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

main() {
    pid_t pid;

    if ( (pid = fork()) == -1 )
        printf("could not fork");
    else if ( pid == 0 ) { /* child */
        sleep(1); /* wait for the parent to prepair */
        kill(getpid(),SIGSTOP); /* send SIGSTOP to myself */
        while(1); /* loop */
    }
    else { /* parent */
        int stat;
        waitpid(pid,&stat,WUNTRACED|WCONTINUED);
        while ( WIFSTOPPED(stat) || WIFCONTINUED(stat) ) {
            if ( WIFSTOPPED(stat) ) {
                printf("child was stopped\n");
                /* if the next line is uncommented, SIGCONT is caught property */
                /* kill(pid,SIGCONT); */
            }
            if ( WIFCONTINUED(stat) ) {
                /* this part is never reached */
                printf("child was continued\n");
                kill(pid,SIGTERM); /* terminate child */
            }
            waitpid(pid,&stat,WUNTRACED|WCONTINUED);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using MacOS X / Darwin, not mainline FreeBSD installed on Apple hardware?

Comment: Yes, MacOS X/ Darwin. will modify my question.

Comment: just in case https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19314 (Darwin) probably could give you some hints

Comment: Why do you have FreeBSD tagged for this? OSX is not FreeBSD.